# please , what i can do to resolve this issue when i want to commit from eclipse to github?

Tags: eclipse, github, commit

Can't connect to any repository: https://github.com/KJ-jamila/Alten.git (Duplicate remote ref update is illegal. Affected remote name: refs/heads/master)

Comment: What are the exact steps to reproduce the issue and when and where is the error message displayed? It's unclear to me what you mean, since in Git you only _commit_ changes to the local repository and _push_ things to a remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by going into the config file in the .git directory in Eclipse, which can be easily be seen in the Git perspective and removing the duplicate branch.